# Why do I have to include a return statement in my pyramid view callable?

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to form the view callable for the home page of my pyramid application and am reading about the view callables here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/views.html

But it seems like you always have to have a return statment at the end. I don't understand this. I don't want the view callable to return anything. If I was going to write it in english (not python code) I would put

```
@view_config(route_name='home_page', renderer='templates/edit.pt')
def home_page(request):
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        name= request.params['name']
        body = request.params['body']
        page=Page(name,body)
        DBSession.add(page)
        return HTTPFound(Location=request.route_url('view_page',pagename=name))
    return {the edit.pt template i mentioned in the first line}
```

but it doesn't seem like there is any way to do this. I have to return a string, or a dictionary, or something. How can i tell this to python. So if people submit that form, then return that HTTPFound statement, but if they don't just render the edit template.

Comment: Note that in this case (edit form) you actually *do want* to return something from the view function if you want to populate the form with the current values stored in your model (Page). I guess you'll need to find the Page object being edited in the database and pass it to the template to populate all the inputs and textareas. In some rare cases you do not need to pass anything to the template (think of a primitive "Add new item" form), in which case you can just return None or an empty dict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, use the latest Pyramid docs version (for Pyramid version 1.4) http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html (since I assume you are using the latest Pyramid version).

As for the `return` statement, you **usually `return` a dictionary**, even if it's empty, because your Chameleon template file (*edit.pt*) is expecting it. `@view_config(renderer='templates/edit.pt')` tells the function on the next line to pass the dictionary to *edit.pt*, so the templating engine can replace the variables within the template.

**`HTTPFound()`**, on the other hand, **bypasses the template** (`renderer` argument of `@view_config()` is ignored, *i.e.* **no template is used**) and does an internal **redirect** to another route that your `__init__.py` will dictate. Now whether that new route uses a template/renderer in its `@view_config` is independent from the previous function that skipped the renderer.

Your `return` statement on the last line should be **`return {}`** if there are no variables in the template that you want filled.

Please let me know how I can make this even more clear for you, if needed.

Comment: That was a terrific explanation and completely answers my question, but there is one thing i still do not understand. On my edit.pt template I have an input form that includes a text area with tal:content="page.data". This form should not be populated when the user visits the home page, so there is no need to pass anything into the dictionary in the return statment, correct? page.data is meant to be saved to the database upon form submission for a new entry in the database (created through that return HTTP statement). Now I am getting a name error for page.data and am wondering if thats why.

Comment: I think you're looking to pre-populate the form with previous data in case there is a submission error. For this, you can put a conditional statement (`if`/`else` using "Chameleon template code") before `page.data` to ensure that this variable exists (because the first time you load the page, it obviously won't exist since the user hasn't yet submitted that form with a value in that field).